# If f is a closed surjection then for any open subset U of X,show Fr[f(cl(U)] subset of f(cl(U) intersection f(X-U). Here Fr(A) denotes cl(A) - int(A)

Tags: general-topology

We are given that f is closed and onto and an open subset U of but what to do next Plz Give any idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f:X\rightarrow Y.$

$$Y\setminus int(f(cl(U)))=cl(Y\setminus f(cl(U)))\subseteq cl(f(X)\setminus f(U))$$

Since $(X\setminus U)$ is closed in $X$, $f(X\setminus U)$ is closed in $Y$(note:f is closed).
Maybe, $cl(f(X)\setminus f(U))\subseteq f(X\setminus U).$

If it's true, then we get 
$$Fr(f(cl(U)))=f(cl(U)) \cap (Y\setminus      int(f(cl(U))))\subseteq f(cl(U)) \cap f(X\setminus U)$$